# ASP Button Click not fire in server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, modal-dialog

The problem occured when im trying to fire button in bootstrap modal,
This is the first time this problem occured for me and i dont any clue for the reason

```
                <div class="modal fade" id="cancelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> ביטול שיעור</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtNewDay">
                                    סיבת הביטול:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="CancelationReasonTxt" runat="server" CssClass ="form-control" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CancelButton" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                   <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" ID="CancelButton" OnClick="CancelButton_OnClick"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        סגור</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Button "CancelButton" not fire the event click "CancelButton_OnClick" on the server side.

Thanks alot

EDIT:
when i removed the trigger i got :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `UpdateMode="conditional"`. By default it is *UpdateMode="Always"*

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If the UpdateMode property is set to Conditional, and one of the following conditions occurs:

1. You call the *Update* method of the UpdatePanel control explicitly.
2. The postback is caused by a control that is defined as a trigger by using the Triggers property of the UpdatePanel control. In this scenario, the control explicitly triggers an update of the panel content. The control can be either inside or outside the UpdatePanel control that defines the trigger.
3. The ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to true and a child control of the UpdatePanel control causes a postback. A child control of a nested UpdatePanel control does not cause an update to the outer UpdatePanel control unless it is explicitly defined as a trigger.

Comment: @user1940350, are you sure you have a script manager added in a page?

Comment: yes, im sure. i have more modals and update panels in the page that works fine

Comment: bacause i added trigger of the button click in the Calendar update panel and the code works fine

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know why, but i added trigger for the control in the exception and now the cancelbutton fired and the update panel work fine.

thanks for everybody